# How to test APIs with Scala (SDET Automation)?

Tags: scala, akka, scalatest, akka-http

I am new to Scala (came from a Java background). I am a SDET. I have learned the syntax through courses on Pluralsight/Udemy and now I want to learn how to test REST APIs using Scala.

I have read online about Akka-http-testkit, Play, ScalaTest, and I have looked at some repo's on Git, but honestly there is no tutorial I have found that really explains things and the documentation for these frameworks is not something I can wrap my head around. Then there is things about Actors having a service and a server, etc. ... I'm lost!

Is there any help I can get that will really give me a step by step on explanation and execution? Many thanks.

Comment: What is the API written in? Http4s. Akka-http, Play, Finatra, Finch ?  Akka Testkit will not do anything if the API is written in Play.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSBUwLT9zXhUalKfJrc2q2A/playlists) to know details about Scala and development with testing .

Coming to your questions - Here are the [video1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g-0inzMUsRg&list=PLJGDHERh23x-4bTASKbtwhhAuP6rYQJqE&index=1), [video2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-0PsDZZUi5c&list=PLJGDHERh23x-4bTASKbtwhhAuP6rYQJqE&index=2) and [code](https://github.com/DevInsideYou/credit-card-generator-and-validator) link how to use ScalaTest framework.

Comment: These are all unit tests, I believe the OP is looking for integration or feature tests.

Comment: @sinanspd I provided some tutorial link, from where he can start using ScalaTest framework. Not sure what he is looking for as he is bit lost, I just helped him from where he can start. And SDET is not only about integrating or feature tests, It starts from Unit testing, Component, Integrations, feature and more about developing automation framework that cover these types of testing. So I believe stating from Unit test ll help him to understand how features work.